# Vue transitions are not working for router-link and $router.push

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-transitions

I've the following App.vue file:

```js
<script setup>
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
</script>

<template>
  <RouterView v-slot="{ Component }">
    <transition :name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <component :is="Component" />
    </transition>
  </RouterView>
</template>
```

And the following router file:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "signin",
      component: () => import("../views/signin.vue"),
    },
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      name: "dashboard",
      component: () => import("../views/dashboard.vue"),
    },
  ],
});

export default router;
```

When I run my application and click any link, no transition is happening, no matter if it use `$router.push("/dashboard");` or `router-link(to="/dashboard" active-class="active")`. I've already checked out many other questions and tutorials but unfortunately it's still not working. Any idea why no transition happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can change in your code.

First, you don't need to declare an import for `RouterView` as it is [globally registered](https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/242#issuecomment-627801480). As long as `vue-router` is installed in your project, you can safely use `RouterView` or `router-view` directly on your template.

Second, you need to change your `name` prop to a static prop. Writing `:name="fade"` means you are passing the value of the variable `fade` to `name`. Based on your code, I'm assuming `fade` is not a variable but a string which means you need to change your prop to `name="fade"`. Read more about [static and dynamic props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#static-vs-dynamic-props).

Lastly, transitions require the use of CSS. Since you're declaring a [named transition](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#named-transitions), you need to add the following CSS:

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Notice the use of `fade` in the CSS. That is the value provided in the `name` prop which means if you have for example:

```html
<transition name="slide-in" mode="out-in">
```

then your CSS should have `.slide-in-enter-active`, `.slide-in-enter-leave`, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```html
<component :is="Component" />
```

to

```html
<component :key="$route.path" :is="Component"/>
```

The transition is not detecting the views changing, so you need to provide something that'll change for it.
Also, remember that `fade` has to be an actual animation in your CSS, e.g.:

```css
    .fade-enter-active
    {
        animation: fade 0.25s;
    }

    .fade-leave-active
    {
        animation: fade 0.25s reverse;
    }

    @keyframes fade 
    {
        from
        {
            opacity: 0%;
        }

        to
        {
            opacity: 100%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was what I was missing. Needed to track the path changes to trigger the transition on page change.